# Correct syntax for creating a parquet table with CTAS at a specified location

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, create-table, parquet

I'm trying to create a table stored as `parquet` with `spark.sql` with a pre-specified external location, but I appear to be missing something, or something is omitted from the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html).

My reading of the documentation suggests the following should work:

```
create table if not exists schema.test
using PARQUET
partitioned by (year, month)
location 's3a://path/to/location'
as select '1' test1, true test2, '2017' year, '01' month
```

But this returns the error:

> mismatched input 'location' expecting (line 4, pos 0)

The documentation suggests `external` is automatically implied by setting `location`, but anyway adding `create external table` gives the same error.

I was able to successfully create an empty table with similar syntax:

```
create external table if not exists schema.test
(test1 string, test2 boolean)
partitioned by (year string, month string)
stored as PARQUET
location 's3a://path/to/location'
```

My alternative is to save the `select` results to a `parquet` at `/path/to/location` directly first, then create a table pointing to this, but this seems roundabout when the original syntax seems valid and designed for this purpose.

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Works fine for me (2.3-RC1), but just to point out - Databricks documentation is not the same as Spark documentation.

Comment: @user6910411 thanks; where is the Spark documentation, for the record?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ Databricks docs should do most of the time, but you have to keep in mind that different platforms have their own extensions, so documentation doesn't necessary reflect Spark's features. Works on 2.2 as well.

Comment: @michaelchirico found any workaround?